# Pass a variable in a functional component to a class component

Tags: reactjs

I've a ToysPage.js with a class component and a SearchFeature.js with a functional component (child of ToysPage).
I made a searchBar in SearchFeature.js with hooks and with console.log I can see that it works. But how can I pass the const filteredToys to the state toysFiltered in ToysPage.js?

**ToysPage.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class ToysPage extends Component {
  state = {
    toys: undefined,
    toysFiltered: undefined,
  };

//Here I call all the toys through Axios and insert them in toys and toysFiltered

return (
      <>
        <div className="container">
          <div className="row">
            <SearchSide
              toysFiltered={this.state.toysFiltered}/>
            <ToysSide toys={this.state.toysFiltered} />
          </div>
        </div>
      </>
    );
  }
}

function SearchSide({ toysFiltered }) {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="col-3">
        <SearchFeature toysFiltered={toysFiltered} />
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

**SearchFeature.js**

```
import React, { useState, useMemo } from "react";

export default function SearchFeature({ toysFiltered }) {
  const [query, setQuery] = useState("");
  const [filteredToys, setFilteredToys] = useState(toysFiltered);

  useMemo(() => {
    const result = toysFiltered.filter((toy) => {
      return toy.titulo.toLowerCase().includes(query.toLowerCase());
    });

    setFilteredToys(result);
  }, [toysFiltered, query]);

  return (
    <div className="form-group">
      <label>Search a Toy</label>
      <input
        type="text"
        className="form-control"
        placeholder="Search"
        value={query}
        onChange={(e) => {
          setQuery(e.target.value);
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: You want to pass a value from `<SearchFeature>` back to its parent? By passing a function from the parent component to the child component as with an other non-state mgmt-architected app.

Comment: Ah thanks, so instead of making the function UseMemo of filter in `<SearchFeature>` I have to make it in `<ToysPage>` and pass it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some state in a child component, `SearchFeature`, that you would like in the parent component `ToysPage`. The usual pattern for this is to [lift the state](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) out of `SearchFeature`, which you have partially done.

You're *almost* doing this correctly. You pass a list of filtered toys into `SearchFeature`, but that list is only being used as a default value for a duplicate state variable in `SearchFeature`, and changes don't flow up to the parent:

```js
// filteredToys has the real state. toysFiltered is just a default value.
const [filteredToys, setFilteredToys] = useState(toysFiltered);
```

Instead, leave the state variable in the parent, and send changes up from the search component.

Also, `useMemo` shouldn't have side effects. I've changed it to `useEffect` to be safe. There is a way to do this with `useMemo`, but that's out of the scope of the question.

---

**in ToysPage.js**

Add a setter function:

```js
<SearchSide
  toysFiltered={this.state.toysFiltered}
  setToysFiltered={
    newFilterList => this.setState({...this.state, toysFiltered: newFilterList})}
/>
```

Pass it through from `SearchSide` into `SearchFeature`:

```
function SearchSide({ toysFiltered, setToysFiltered }) {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="col-3">
        <SearchFeature toysFiltered={toysFiltered} setToysFiltered={setToysFiltered} />
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

**SearchFeature.js**

```js
export default function SearchFeature({ toysFiltered, setToysFiltered }) {
  const [query, setQuery] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    const result = toysFiltered.filter((toy) => {
      return toy.titulo.toLowerCase().includes(query.toLowerCase());
    });

    setToysFiltered(result);
  }, [setToysFiltered, query]);

  // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried your resolve but I get on console this warning loop:

`index.js:1 Warning: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component calls setState inside useEffect, but useEffect either doesn't have a dependency array, or one of the dependencies changes on every render.`

And I can't type on the searchBar either

Comment: Yep, that's my bad. Remove `toysFiltered` from the dependency array in `useEffect`: `[setToysFiltered, query]`

Comment: Just a note: this answer will work just fine, but a more "correct" solution would be to lift both the `query` state and the `toysFiltered` state out of `SearchFeature`. Then you can handle filtering in `ToysPage` instead of `SearchFeature` If you do that, you won't need to pass `toysFiltered` or `setToysFiltered` to `SearchFeature` at all.

Comment: Thanks for the response Joshua, it worked for me. And sorry to the late answer!